# Retirar um espaço especifico em uma string

Tags: java, android, string

Estou com dificuldade para implementar `replace` em uma `String` no Android Studio.

Preciso que seja retirado um determinado espaço em branco na `String`.

Exemplos reais:

- **8 hrs 2 mins**
- **1 dia 2 mins**

Preciso que o texto fique da seguinte forma:

- **8hrs 2mins**
- **1dia 2mins**

Se alguém poder me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Você disse que não sabe quais sequências "hrs", "mins" vêm na string. E quais **podem** vir, você sabe? Se souber, basta chamar `replace()` para cada uma que funcionará sem problemas. Senão, veja minha solução com regex.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver @dnsfirmino?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você disse que o formato pode ser variado ( `min`, `mins`, `miNs`, etc...) vou postar uma outra forma de fazer considerando os espaços e não as palavras.

Você pode usar a classe [**`Scanner`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) para isto, o pessoal só lembra dela para fazer leitura com `System.in` mas ela tem vários recursos úteis. [**`Scanner#next()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) retorna o próximo token de entrada e estes tokens são, por padrão, separados por espaços.

Se o formato de entrada for sempre este que você postou, então você pode usar `next() + next()` para pegar os tokens de dois em dois. Ficaria assim:

```
TOKENS:        8      |   hrs    |    2    |   mins

               ^           ^          ^         ^
               |           |          |         |
               |           |          |         |
CHAMADAS:    next()  +   next()  |  next()  +  next()

                     ^                      ^
                     |                      |

RESULTADO:          8hrs         |        2mins
```

Eu fiz um método com essa lógica:

```
public String format(String string){
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(string);
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   while(scanner.hasNext())
      sb.append(scanner.next())
        .append(scanner.next())
        .append(" ");
   return sb.toString();
}
```

E nos testes os resultados foram:

```
String test1 = "50 min";
String test2 = "20 hrs 50 mins";
String test3 = "1 d 20 hrs 50 min";
String test4 = "3 meses 15 dias 20 horas 50 minutos";

System.out.println(format(test1)); // 50min 
System.out.println(format(test2)); // 20hrs 50mins 
System.out.println(format(test3)); // 1d 20hrs 50min 
System.out.println(format(test4)); // 3meses 15dias 20horas 50minutos
```

#### [Exemplo online](http://ideone.com/Xb77TK)

Comment: PS: Eu escolheria a resposta do Piovezan.

Answer (score 10):

```
String comEspaco = "8 hrs 2 mins";
String semEspaco = comEspaco.replace(" hr", "hr").replace(" min", "min");
```

Solução alternativa com *regex* sem depender do que vem depois de cada espaço:

```
String comEspaco = "8 hrs 2 mins";
String semEspaco = comEspaco.replaceAll("([0-9]) ", "$1");
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/4kYdX6).

Comment: Muito bom. Estava fazendo minha resposta mas deixa pra lá.
Perfeito.

Comment: Olá obrigado pelo retorno, desta forma funcionaria mas nem sempre a string vem com este formato, pode ser que venha assim 1 dia 20 min.

Comment: Então você deve alterar a sua pergunta.

Comment: Mas ai basta você tratar com um laço.

Comment: Todas os trechos `" dia"`, `" hr"`, `" min"`, etc. que você sabe que podem vir, você tem condições de remover o espaço usando essa solução. Os trechos que ele não encontrar ele não substitui. Agora, se você não sabe de antemão os trechos que podem vir, tem que informar o que devemos esperar que venha para que possamos sugerir um regex ou alguma outra forma.

Comment: Pode fazer com regex tambem, identificando uma string numerica, se econtrar retira o espaço depois dela, tendo assim hrs , mins, segs ...

Comment: Incluí uma solução alternativa com regex que não depende das sequências "dia", "min", etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
String comEspaco = "8 hrs 2 mins";
String semEspaco;

if (comEspaco.constains("hrs")){
    semEspaco = comEspaco.replace(" hrs", "hrs").replace(" mins", "mins")
} else{
    semEspaco = comEspaco.replace(" dia", "dia").replace(" hrs", "hrs")
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela gentileza @sicachester

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma possível é usar um StringBuffer e usar o método `replace()`:

```
String hora = "8 hrs 2 mins";
int firstSpace = hora.indexOf(" ");
int lastSpace = hora.lastIndexOf(" ");
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(hora);

buf.replace(firstSpace, firstSpace + 1, "");
buf.replace(lastSpace-1, lastSpace, "");//Note que após o replace anterior o buffer tem menos um caracter

System.out.println(buf.toString());
```

Veja a funcionar no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/q8S6EZ)

Uma outra forma usando `subString()`

Declare um método que faça o replace em uma determinada posição:

```
public static String replaceCharAt(String s, int pos, String c) {
    return s.substring(0, pos) + c + s.substring(pos + 1);
}
```

Utilize-a da seguinte forma:

```
String hora = "8 hrs 2 mins";
int firstSpace = hora.indexOf(" ");

String temp = replaceCharAt(hora, firstSpace, "");

int lastSpace = temp.lastIndexOf(" ");
String horaSemEspacos = replaceCharAt(temp, lastSpace, "");

System.out.println(horaSemEspacos);
```

Veja a funcionar no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/m8kha0)

Comment: Obrigado! Fiz utilizando sua recomendação e funcionou para todas as situações.